#  AnimationSet plays in reverse order

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm using an AnimationSet to do many Translate animations. In this example I want to move an ImageView from 0 to 700 (offscreen) and from -700 to 0 (the view move to the extreme right and re-enter from the extreme left). I use this code:

```
    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
    set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    set.setFillEnabled(true);
    if(traject!=null){
        TranslateAnimation tmpAnim = null;
        set.setDuration(duration);
        int d = traject.size()!=0 ? duration/traject.size() : duration;

        for(int i =0; i<traject.size();i++){
            tmpAnim = new TranslateAnimation( traject.get(i).getStartX(),
                                            traject.get(i).getEndX(),
                                            traject.get(i).getStartY(),
                                            traject.get(i).getEndY() );
            tmpAnim.setDuration(d);
            tmpAnim.setFillAfter(true);
            tmpAnim.setStartOffset(d*i);
            set.addAnimation(tmpAnim);
        }
    }
```

- traject is an arraylist holding each TranslateAnimation start and end points

But in my test example the animation goes from -700 to 700. I tried switching the order of the TranslateAnimations, using setStartTime() instead of setStartOffset(), skipping the call to setStartOffset(), the result is the same. Do you have any idea on what I am missing ?